# flash as3 - assigning a set of event handlers to a set of movieclips

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, class, addeventlistener

I have a movieclip in my library which contains a set of menu controls. Each control has a series of actions it will perform on rollover, rollout, and click, plus a few properties that should always be set (buttonMode, mouseChildren).

In my class, instead of selecting each button's event listeners, is there a way to apply a set of event listeners and properties to all of the clips? They are at different levels and locations within the menu, but they all have the same actions: gotoAndPlay("over")", buttonMode = true, etc.

Here's how my class is set up:

```
package {

  import flash.display.*;
    import flash.events.*; 
    import com.greensock.*;
    import com.greensock.easing.*;

  public class Main extends MovieClip {

    public var menuInstance:PanoMenu;
    private var menuTopRef;

    public function Main() {
        menuInstance = new PanoMenu();
        menuInstance.x = -43;
        menuInstance.y = 23;
        menuTopRef = menuInstance.menuTop;
        menuTopRef.buttonMode = true; 
        menuTopRef.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK,menuTopClick); //MH - want to do this for all clips in the menu, with their own unique callbacks specified
        addChild(menuInstance);
        trace ("main");
    }

    private function menuTopClick(e:MouseEvent){
        trace ("top click");
    }

  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While Reshape Media's answer is a good way to handle the Click events, the button behavior should probably be handled by creating a Class and applying it to all of your button-ish MovieClips. Or, the old school way is to just make a button Symbol (which will be an instance of SimpleButton) that pretty much works like you want without any extra code.

Answer (score 0):

Based on your situation, you don't need different handlers.  What you can do is send ALL events from ALL buttons (in the menu) to a single handler and then do a switch case to check the name of the button and go from there.

```
//random menu items
var menu_item_1:Sprite = new Sprite;
var menu_item_2:Sprite = new Sprite;
var menu_item_3:Sprite = new Sprite;

//give them unique names
menu_item_1.name = 'item 1';
menu_item_2.name = 'item 2';
menu_item_3.name = 'item 3';

//define an array and add the SAME listener         
var menu_items:Array = [menu_item_1,menu_item_2,menu_item_3];
for(var i:Number = 0; i<menu_items.length; i++){
    var item:Sprite = menu_items[i] as Sprite;
    item.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK,onClick);
}

//listen for all button clicks
//do a switch case to map the clicks
function onClick(e:MouseEvent):void{

    switch(e.target.name){

        case 'item 1':
            //do something
            break;

        case 'item 2':
            //do something
            break;  

        case 'item 2':
            //do something
            break;  
    }

}
```